# Регулярные выражения nginx

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте, есть правило для вирт. хоста nginx

```
  location ~ /([A-Z0-9-_]+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?user=$1;
  }
```

как только я пытаюсь добавить перед A-Z ещё и a-z (тоесть чтобы буквы на маленьком регистре были разрешены) то при заходе на данный юрл, php файл скачивается но не открывается, как это вообще понять? Я же просто добавил маленькие буквы к паттерну

Comment: 1. на какой «данный»? 2. перенесите `-` в начало или конец перечисления: `[-a-z0-9_]` или `[a-z0-9_-]`. иначе вы сбиваете с толку движок регулярных выражений.

Comment: попробуйте указать "~*" вместо "~"